# Which FIDE ratings correspond to the different Stockfish levels at 5+3?

Tags: fide, rating, stockfish, lichess

Lichess has a `Play With The Computer` option on its main site, which offers Stockfish levels 1 through 8.

What would their FIDE ELOs be with time control set to 5+3?

(Some people on Lichess have FIDE ratings, so if they play Stockfish at different levels often enough, perhaps one could use those games to estimate the different Stockfish levels' playing strengths. And perhaps this has already been done?)

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming you play one of them at 5+3 time controls and are as likely to lose as you are to win, then how good would you be on FIDE's rating scale?

Ratings are not absolute values of chess ability or play. They are relative measures within a certain pool of players at a given time period. Hence there is no possibility of making such a comparison with any degree of accuracy.